# Artifactory repo has bad path for artifact, any way to fix path request?

Tags: maven, artifactory

Recently my company blocked requests to outside repositories, and an artifact that is required by a component of my project is available only on one repo where it is incorrectly set up.

The path requested is:

`/reponame/com/group/name/artifact-name/1.0.0.pom`

But it is found in the company repository here:

`/reponame/com.group.name/artifact-name/1.0.0.pom`

Other outside repositories I have seen have it in the former path.

Is there a way to have my project request the latter path instead, some other way around?  I don't have the artifact requirement in my project, it's a dependency of a dependency requirement I have.

I have tried to get help from the artifactory admins but they are completely slammed, stating I won't have a solution for a couple weeks (I need it faster than that).

Comment: Your project unfortunately now relies on artifactory being set up correctly for something not in Maven Central, which makes your build brittle. You may want to handle that technical debt now by not doing that but instead only use things found in Maven Central or your own stuff. This is not a small task but now seems to be a good time.

Comment: What about simply moving or copying it in Artifactory to the correct path?

Comment: I don't have access to change repositories and I cannot use Maven Central - no outside repositories as per company policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the best path is for me to install my own maven repo on my laptop so I don't get stopped when my company's artifactory support is lacking.